# Rearranging a simple algebraic expression

Tags: simplifying-expressions, polynomials, algebra

I have a polynomial of variables $x,y$, where $|x|<1$ and $|y|<1$. When I apply the `Simplify` function to this expression, I get an expression of the form

$(x-1) (y-1)^3 y + x^n (x-a)^5 (y-b)^7 + ..$, where $|a| \geq 1$ and  $|b| \geq 1$.

Contrary, I want Mathematica to give me an expression of the form
$(1-x) (1-y)^3 y+ x^n (a-x)^5(y-b)^7 + ...$

That is, I want in the simplified expression $(a-x^n)$ instead of $(x^n-a)$ and $(b-y^n)$ instead of $(y^n-b)$, if $a$, $b$ and $n$ are greater than or equal to $1$. Is there a way to do this by aiding a parameter/ an option to the `Simplify` or `FullSimplify` function? If not, is there any easy way to do it?  I tried doing it with the replacement rule `{(x + a_?NumericQ) :> (-(-a - x))}`, but could not get the desired result.

Edit: Here is the Mathematica code for the expression I want to rewrite

```
(x - 1) (y - 1)^3 y + x^3 (x - 1)^5 (y - 2)^7 + x^3 (x^2 - 3) (y^3 - 3 )
```

and here is the desired result

```
(1 - x) (1 - y)^3 y + x^3 (1 - x)^5 (2 - y)^7 + x^3 (3 - x^2) (3 - y^3).
```

Comment: Please upload Mathematica code for the expression. Thanks.

Comment: Mathematical uses its own way to order terms. It needs this order to work. When you need to look at the result in the habitual form for whatever reason, you can apply `TraditionalForm` to it.  For example, have a look at `(x - 1) (y - 1)^3 y // TraditionalForm`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"];
expr = (x - 1) (y - 1)^3 y + x^3 (x - 1)^5 (y - 2)^7 + 
  x^3 (x^2 - 3) (y^3 - 3)
```

[image]

```
Replace[expr, (Plus[a_?Negative, b_])^c_. :> 
   g^c (Abs@a - b) , {1, ∞}] /. {g^x_?EvenQ :> 1, 
  g^x_?OddQ :> -1}
```

[image]